# How to remove a tray icon from Blackberry OS programatically

Tags: blackberry

ok. So I am refering to the icons for an application that appear just below the time, with a number beside them. I am maintaining a blackberry application and I am finding the icon is not unset when the count is zero.

This happens to be blackberry OS 6.

Is see a call to this function:

NotificationsManager.cancelImmediateEvent(APP_ID, NEW_MESSAGE_EVENT, null, null);

Which I am not sure does the intended behavior. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

These are known as ApplicationIndicators.  You might have a look at:

1. [How to use ApplicationIndicator?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-ApplicationIndicator/td-p/160089)
2. [`ApplicationIndicatorRegistry` javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.html)
3. [`ApplicationIndicator` javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationIndicator.html)